# Show that $Z(G) = \cap_{a \in G} C(a)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Show that $Z(G) = \cap_{a \in G} C(a)$.

Let $a \in Z(G)$. Then $ax=xa$ for all $x$ in $G$. In particular we can say that $ax_1=x_1a$ and $ax_2=x_2a$ and $ax_3=x_3a$ and so on ($x_i$ are elements of $G$). This is nothing but intersection of all subgroups of form $C(a)$. However I doubt my way of doing this question. Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: What is $C(a)$?

Comment: @McFry Centralizer of a

Comment: Use the standard way of proving two sets are equal.  Prove the LHS is a subset of the RHS and the RHS is a subset of the LHS.

Comment: Fundamentally, this is exact, but one doesn't distinguish which inclusion(s) are proved.

Comment: @Bernard i didnot quite follow you

Comment: @Gathdi: I mean for me,  it is unclear whether you prove $Z(G)$ is contained in the intersection, or the reverse, or both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this is the shortest:
$$\begin{align}
x\in Z(G)&\iff \forall a\in G,\;ax=xa\\
&\iff\forall a\in G,\;x\in C(a)\\
&\iff x\in\bigcap_{a\in G}C(a).
\end{align}$$

Comment: where is defect in my proof

Comment: @Gathdi: as I said in a previous comment – no real defect, just a little unclear what exactly you're proving. The way I write it is clearer to me, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

$$Z(G) = \{g \in G \mid \forall a \in G: ga = ag\} = \bigcap_{a \in G} \{g \in G \mid ga = ag\} = \bigcap_{a \in G} C(a)$$

Answer (score 2):

I tried to write a proof in the style you're going for.

Suppose $x\in Z(G)$. Then, $xa=ax$ for all $a\in G$, and hence, $x\in C(a)$ for all $a\in G$. Thus, $x\in\bigcap_{a\in G}C(a)$. Conversely, suppose $x\in\bigcap_{a\in G}C(a)$ for all $a\in G$. Then, $xa=ax$ for all $a\in G$, so that $x\in Z(G)$.

By mutual inclusion, $Z(G)=\bigcap_{a\in G}C(a)$.